# Regex: only allow a single slash at the end?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, php-5.3

How can use regex to make sure that is only a **single slash** end the end of an URL or any input string?

```
$url = 'http://example.com//';
if(!preg_match('/\/$/', $url))
{
    echo 'the url must ends with a \'/\'';
}
```

This accepts two or more slashes which is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do like this:

```
~(?:[^/]|^)/$~
```

I have not tested it, the idea is to test if there is not a `/` before the `/` at the end of the string (and in this version to allow the start of a string as well, so the `"/"` string is valid as well.

Comment: Oh yeh, you're right I just tested and it is now obvious why. Ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

You're not asking for it to end with only a single `/`; all you've said is that the end of the string must have a `/` before it.

Try (in extended format:)

```
[^/]   # anything BUT a /
\/     # a /
$      # end of string
```

or in the regular, compressed format:

```
[^/]\/$
```

instead.

(As an aside: almost every web server won't care that you have an extra /...you probably don't have to do this, or if you do for an internal application, are probably missing a lot of corner cases.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using a negative lookbehind:

```
if(!preg_match('#(?<!\/)\/{0,1}$#',url) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using regex completely like this:

```
$str = 'http://localhost//';
$dslash = '//';
if (substr_compare($str, $dslash, -2, 2) === 0)
   echo "Double slash\n"; // gets printed
else
   echo "No double slash\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **Perl** code, but **PHP** should be similar >>

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$url = 'http://example.com//';
print "Error...\n" if $url =~ m/\/\/+$/;
```